# upper some specific letters

Tags: python, string, loops, uppercase

Upper only letters that I have indexes on the list (PYTHON)

```
s = "string"
l = [1,3]
# output is: sTrIng
```

Tried this but it wont work

```
for i in l:
    s[i] = s[i].upper()
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable. If you want to check by index, you can for example use a list and update the value by index (and check if that index exists first).

Then at the end, join the characters to a string.

```
s = "string"
result = list(s)
lst = [1, 3]
length = len(result)

for i in lst:
    if i < length:
        result[i] = result[i].upper()

print("".join(result))
```

Output

```
sTrIng
```